# Calling Jersey services from Android, unknown Exception

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, jersey, jersey-client

I'm trying to call a web service I made using Jersey.
I tested the services by calling them from a console java app, and its working perfectly fine.

When calling from Android, it first gave me android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException, I searched and found out that i should use AsyncTask to solve that,

the following code crashes when "response.getEntity(String.class)" is called
while calling a get service, if i return the status ( response.getStatus()) instead of getEntity, it works fine. But the same thing doesnt work in case of a post request. getEntity() crashes on both

```
    public String postTest(String arg){
        Log.d("Service", "postRegister1");
        client = Client.create();
        WebResource service=client.resource(getBaseURI());
        Log.d("Service", "postRegister2");

        Form form = new Form();
        form.add("arg", "lol");

        int status;
        ClientResponse response=null;
        try{
            response = service.path("test").get(ClientResponse.class);
            //post
            // response = service.path("post").path("test").post(ClientResponse.class,from);

            Log.d("Service", "postRegister3");
            status = response.getStatus();

            //comment out the following if statement and the code will work perfectly fine, returning the stats
            if(status == 200){
                return response.getEntity(String.class);
            }
            return String.valueOf(response.getStatus());
        }
        catch(ClientHandlerException e){
            Log.d("Exception1",e.getMessage()+ " ");
        }
        catch(UniformInterfaceException e){
            Log.d("Exception2",e.getMessage()+ " ");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception3",e.getMessage()+ " ");
        }

        return "exception";

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("doInback", params[0]);

        return postTest(params[0]);
    }
```

the code above code is part of the class:

```
public class Service extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
```

and is called like:

```
try {
        alert(new Service().execute("lol").get(),view);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the alert method just displays an alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using a library for implementing [Async Http
client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/).

The tutorial which i followed can be found [here](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-restful-webservice-tutorial-how-to-call-restful-webservice-in-android-part-3/).